# Kotlin format CSV with header

Tags: java, android, csv, kotlin

I want to change my CSV format file **by adding a header with his list of names and date**

here is what I tried and it looks like this :
[image: test.png]

```
fun export(path: File?) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            selected?.let { it ->
                val file = File(path, "${it.name}.csv")
                val tags = repository.getTagsOfList(it.id.toInt())
                val tagsCSV = "TAG: ${tags.map { it.name }}; DATE: ${tags.map { it.date }}"
                file.writeText(
                    "LIST NAME: ${it.name}; " +
                            tagsCSV)
                val csv = file.readText()
                println(csv)
            }
        }
    }
```

but I want this format:

[image: version2.png]

**EDIT:**
I used apache-commons.csv, it's easier but i have an exception :

```
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            selected?.let { it ->
                val file = "${it.name}.csv"
                val writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(file))
                val csvPrinter =
                    CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader("LIST NAME;TAGS;DATE"))
                val tags = repository.getTagsOfList(it.id.toInt())

                // push the values into the file.
                csvPrinter.printRecord(
                    "${it.name};${tags.map { it.name }};${tags.map { it.date }}")

                //pushes the file and its content into the local system
                csvPrinter.flush()
                csvPrinter.close()
                println(csvPrinter)
            }
        }
    }

    FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
        Process: fr.pageup.techcare.readapp.debug, PID: 11435
        java.nio.file.FileSystemException: yuyu.csv: Read-only file system
            at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
            at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:434)
```

Comment: You are probably trying to write it to somewhere you don't have permission to write, it is unclear from both code examples where exactly you are trying to write the file and especially on later versions of Android, there is less scope to use File objects.

Comment: Yes, i put this on my fragment : ```binding.btnExport.setOnClickListener {
            val path = requireContext().getExternalFilesDir("lists")
            viewModel.export(path)
        }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not trying to create the file in the same location in each example.

When you wrote the file yourself you append the "name.csv" to the path returned by `getExternalFilesDir("lists")`

In the apache csv example you do not use the value of `getExternalFilesDir("lists")` at all you are trying to write to the current working directory of the process which is a different location to `getExternalFilesDir("lists")`

I'm not a kotlin expert but try replacing

```
val file = "${it.name}.csv"
val writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(file))
```

with

```
val file = File(path, "${it.name}.csv")
file.bufferedWriter().use {
   val csvPrinter .... // rest of writing code here
 }
```

This way the location you are opening the buffered writer at has the value of `path` prepended to it as in the first example

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just saw that I was not using the path variable so it works with this ```fun export(path: File?)``` ```                val file = File(path, "${it.name}.csv")
```

Comment: Please upvote/mark as answered as outlined in the answer that making sure you are trying to write the file in the same location was the solution.